# What are some articles that give reasons for trusting one's perceptions, memory, or reasoning?

Tags: epistemology, perception

Note that by trusting one's perceptions, I mean trusting that one *has* perceptions, rather than trusting that one's perceptions are "accurate". Preferably, the articles should be rigorous and high-quality.

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you doubt you have perception?  If you even doubt, that too is a perception.  Perception seems to be one of those self-evident givens upon which everything else is based, so I can't imagine anyone going lower.  However, if there are any works that actually go there, I'd LOVE to know about them.

Comment: @ R. Barzell I don't really see why I should believe something just because it's seems self-evident. Perhaps I don't really understand the concept of being self-evident. (Of course, me writing this comment is due to me acting as if self-evident truths are true.)

Comment: There's nothing to believe or disbelieve.  One doesn't apply beliefs to perceptions, but what they represent.  I see a computer; I can't doubt this, for if I say "I doubt I am seeing a computer", I have asserted the perception I doubted.  However, I can doubt if this computer is an external thing.  If you doubt your perceptions, then you have nothing, for any argument you encounter will also be a perception.  Perceptions are as basic as you get, and they must be taken as a given. Maybe I misunderstood what you meant by perceptions?

Comment: are you asking for evidence in perception being such and such, not natural etc.? i don't think any philosophers would deny there being perception exactly, anymore than they would deny that there are something like persons, even if that is reducible to physics, and not quite as we might think etc.

Comment: @R. Barzell That doesn't really explain why to trust one's perceptions; it just explains that you must in order to come to any beliefs at all. Perhaps one can make no reliable beliefs at all.

Comment: @Kyth'Py1k it sounds like we're talking about 2 different things.  (1) Trusting that one HAS perceptions, and (2) Trusting one's perceptions [i.e.: what they seem to point to].  (1) does not imply (2), but (1) is irreducible in the sense that they are there, and that's that.

Comment: @Kyth'Py1k  Referring to my previous comment... Your question asks (1) but your comments seem to ask (2).  Further, your subject refers to (2) and includes memory and reasoning.  If you flesh out your question, make it & the subject consistent and clarify whether you want (1) or (2), you may get more help. Depending on what you ask, I can provide references to part of your request, but they're all about why you can't trust these things.

Comment: @R.Barzell My mistake. I meant (1). (2) would still be interesting, though.